# zend framework xml api

Tags: zend-framework, xml-parsing

I'm learning the Zend Framework.  So please excuse me if this question is basic.

I want to write a small app driven by a xml api.  The xml returned is below.

What the best way to parse this xml file?
What a good design pattern should I use?  Should I store it in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up extending the Zend_Rest_Client Class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to make into PHP variables for easy use with the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the xml file Zend_Config_Xml.
[Zend Config Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.xml.html)

And for storing this data i would recommend to use the xml structure. It will give more flexibility to the app later on.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this - `Zend_Config` is for config files and the XML given does not look like one. Just use the standard simplexml functions directly.